# How to efficiently remove from list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a use care where I needd to apply set of filters to a list of strings and remove string from the list if has some reason on why it should be filtered out. I am currently doing it like this:

```
private List<Data> applyFilter(Request request) {

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(request.getDataList())) {
            Map<String,Data> map =
                    request.getDataList()
                            .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getId, data -> data));

            for (Data data : request.getDataList()) {
                for (final Filter<Request> filter : filters) {
                    if (filter.getReason(data) != null) {
                        map.remove(data.getId);
                    }
                }
            }

            return (List<Data>) map.values();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this than my current approach ? Also, in my current approach, I will still be iterating on the string if it has the filtered reason because I am iterating on the list. How do I ensure that I dont iterate the string for next filter if it has reason for previous one.

Thanks

Comment: `(List<Data>) asinMap.values();` does not work. First, there is no `asinMap` in this code. Then, assuming that it is supposed to be `map`, its `values()` does not return a `List`, so the cast to `List<Data>` will produce a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8+

```
List<Data> filtered = request.getDataList().stream()
            .filter(data -> filters.stream()
                    .noneMatch(f -> f.getReason(data) != null))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```